# Why AddJoin creates 'one to many' style of output?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

What I am trying to do is to join feature class (2 records/polygons for a test purpose) with excel table(70 records but only 10 would have the same join value, 5 to each record/polygon) using join field created and calculated with use of data from other columns.

What I am getting is a feature class with 10 records (each record created 5 times)

What I want to have is a feature with 2 records + fields from the joining table.

What I am doing excel spreadsheet (with 3000+ records) converted to table (gdb) -->from table i am exporting only 70 with the same 'Option_Name'--> adding joining field --> calculating field (it is text, 150char eg: 15FGS00012/1)

then:

original feature class converted to work feature class (gdb) - adding joining field --> calculating field (same format as in table)

So far so good, I am getting join fields properly calculated, but when I am exporting (or appending, or printing) joining ouput I am always getting that 10 polygons.

What I am doing wrong?

```
import arcpy

Report = r"P:\GIS\FGS Datasets\Data\application_16102016_copy.xls\application__contr$"

output_gdb = r"P:\GIS\Datasets\Data\Data.gdb"
Report_table = r"Report_table"
optionTable = r"S_TABLE"
expression = '"Option_Name" = \'Rural Woods\''

field2 = "GIS_Join"
field2_type1 = "TEXT"
field2_concat1 = "Application_Submitted_Reference"

SDR = r"J:\ArcSDE Connections\GIS.sde"
FC_raw = "GIS.S_RURAL"
FC_FGS = "S_RURAL"
FC_concat1 = "SCHEME_REF"
FC_concat2 = "FGS_OPTION"
FC_featureLayer = "S_RURAL_layer"
expression2 = r"Rural Woods"

final_gdb = r"P:\GIS\Datasets\Data\Data_Final.gdb"
final_feature = final_gdb + "\\" + FC_FGS

arcpy.env.workspace = output_gdb
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace

# export Report.xls to output_gdb as a table
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(Report, output_gdb, Report_table)
print Report_table, " created"

arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(Report_table, optionTable, expression)
print optionTable, " created"

arcpy.AddField_management(Report_table, field2, field2_type1, "", "")

cur1 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Report_table)
for row in cur1:
    if row.Option_Name == "Rural Woods":
        field2_concat3 = "1"
        expression3 = row.getValue(field2_concat1) + r"/" + field2_concat3
        row.setValue(field2, expression3)
        cur1.updateRow(row)
print field2, " in ", Report_table, " calculated"

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(SDR + "\\" + FC_raw, output_gdb, FC_FGS)
print FC_FGS, " created"
arcpy.AddField_management(FC_FGS, field2, field2_type1, "", "")

cur2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(FC_FGS)
for row2 in cur2:
    if row2.FEATDESC == " Publ Access - Rural":
        field1 = "1"
        expression5 = row2.getValue(FC_concat1) + r"/" + field1
        row2.setValue(field2, expression5)
        cur2.updateRow(row2)
print field2, " in ", FC_FGS, " calculated"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC_FGS, FC_featureLayer)

arcpy.AddJoin_management(FC_featureLayer, field2, Report_table, field2, "KEEP_ALL")

del workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = final_gdb
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace

arcpy.DeleteRows_management(final_feature)
print "All data (rows) deleted from the previous version of ", final_feature

arcpy.Append_management(FC_featureLayer, final_feature)

del Report, cur1, cur2
```

Comment: Export to shape file will keep 2

Comment: The [Join Field][1] tool will only select the first value for each record in the joining table, so you should end up with two rows that way. 


  [1]: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm

Comment: @FelixIP I have trried shp... I am still getting 10 features.

Comment: @KJYDavis , I know that I should have get 2 features but it is not happening :/

Comment: Have you tried using JoinField_management instead of AddField_management? I'm pretty sure that will keep the original number of features.

Comment: yes, JoinField do keep only 2 features. it is requiring a bit more post processing work o get to but it is working. But still don't know why AddJoin behave like that.